# Checkpoint linprog

Tags: performance, matlab, optimization, linear-programming, hpc

I have a *very* long running linear program implemented in Matlab that, for small versions of the problem, is solved by linprog.  Going to “full size” on my LP consistently exceeds my maximum allowed job runtime on the system I’m running on.  I’ve had no luck finding a way to checkpoint linprog.  Is there a way?

Comment: Have you tried to test the problem run-time scaling by scaling the problem size within a range of reasonable problem sizes to be able to extrapolate the ( hopefully just polynomial O( n ^ f ) ) projection of run-times? That will position you into be able to negotiate an extra run-time, if you can prove the scaling meets a reasonably extended HPC quota.

Comment: Yes I've done the profiling of the problem as it scales.  It's not badly scaling.  I'm using the interior point algorithm as that was what the profiling indicated was best.  I'm limited by the max job length as a hard constraint; cannot get longer for this single job.

Comment: The problem is 1,484,161 variables with 3,851,432 constraints, but that gets preprocessed which "removed 469,967 inequalities, 361,192 equalities,                                                                                                                                 
377,192 variables, and 3,973,926 non-zero elements."  All-up that ends up with using 11.73 GB of RAM on the system I'm using (a single node).  In ten hours it gets through 80 iterations of the algorithm.  From smaller scale versions of the problem about 300 iteration is likely needed.

Comment: Thanks for your kind adding details. Given a rough estimate of 300 iter.s ( taking ~40 hrs in an as-is mode ) and knowing not more than about 12 GB of the RAM is quite sufficient to proceed to results, lets try to wrap up options: (a) find a way for segmented runs (same problem,using checkpoints) (b) find a problem dual/mathematical re-formulation if faster in about a same RAM footprint (c) seek/organise a less restrictive HPC-infrastructure run of as-is processing + may use (d) public shared, less performant, Octave-node (~USD125/month) or (e) any RAM-size matching COTS computer for ~40 hrs

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. Simplex-based LP solvers have a fantastic restart facility based on an LP basis. Many LP solvers can read and write MPS basis files. I don't think Matlab's LP solver can do that. I know users that never run models from scratch but only from an advanced basis (to be clear: not with Matlab).

Linprog comes with three different algorithms (one simplex, two interior-point). As the model is large, you may try the interior-point solver instead of the default simplex solver. Interior-point solvers are often faster than Simplex solvers on large problems.

Another thing to look at is whether you run out of physical RAM. If a solver starts to use virtual memory, things may become extremely slow.

*The problem is 1,484,161 variables with 3,851,432 constraints, but that gets preprocessed which "removed 469,967 inequalities, 361,192 equalities, 377,192 variables, and 3,973,926 non-zero elements."* This is large but not extremely large. I solve larger models than this on relatively modest hardware. Almost always I solve these in way less than an hour.